# Bottom row of system preferences (third party apps) not showing

Tags: preferences, third-party

In OSX Yosemite I used to have a bottom row of third party preference applets that contained Java, Flash, Air Display etc in System Preferences. This is no longer showing. How do I turn it back on? (I've spent ages googling but not found an answer).

thanks![image: bottom row missing]

Comment: You used to be able to toggle certain pref panes on and off in System Preferences' preferences (yeah, I know). Check to see if they have been toggled off some how.

Comment: Try Cmd/L [show all] or View menu > Customize…  & a Pro Tip - if you use cmd/shift/4 to take pic, then tap space, you can capture an entire window by clicking it, with a nice drop-shadow… sweet… but it will also stop us wondering whether that dark line at the bottom is a poor crop, or potentially a hidden panel ;)

Comment: do they show if you search for it ?

Comment: also there is one more page to look at, click on the right pointing arrow in the menu bar

Comment: thanks all for your quick (and helpful) replies. I already tried View > Customise and View > Show All Preferences (and View > Search). Cmd-L had no effect. The dark line at the bottom _is_ a poor crop (the window cannot be stretched to show more), and the right arrow in the tool bar that looks active in the image is intriguing, but sadly is inactive now and I can't figure out how i got that before. What else can I try? Is there a command line option that might work?

Comment: Can you please add your answer as an answer below and accept it? This will make it easier for future visitors to find it.

Comment: Hi @patrix: done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed homebrew http://brew.sh/ and osquery https://osquery.io/. Then did

```
select * from preferences where domain like "%system%";
```

which showed a list of preference settings that might be interesting. ThirdPartyCount was 0, which I thought was wrong. So I backed up ~Library/Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences.plist and used XCode to edit the value to 3 (which is the value I expected). After a reboot it went back to zero.

After more googling, I found /Library/PreferencePanes contains third party preference panes. The aliases in there were all broken: because I'd manually deleted browser plugins from "/Library/Internet Plug-ins". So i deleted the really-dead aliases, re-installed Java and now the bottom row is displaying as expected. Thanks for all your help.

(footnote: AirDisplay used to have a prefpane i think but the latest version not longer has it)